# Problema deslizamiento de columnas en mi DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy intentando limpiar mi base de datos y uno de los pasos es uniformizar las columnas para que todas tengan el dato al que se refiere cada atributo.
Sin embargo, tengo un problema de deslizamiento de columnas en mi DF. Mi DF inicial sería:

[image: DF inicial]

Lo que quiero hacer es que, cada vez que se encuentre un valor que contenga "m" en la 'Col1', ese valor se mueva a la 'Col2', quedando la 'Col1' como NaN. El resultado esperado sería:

[image: DF final]

He intentado hacer algo como:

```py
mask = sample_df['Col1'].str.contains(r'm', na=True)

sample_df.loc[mask, 'Col2'] = sample_df['Col1']

sample_df.loc[mask, 'Col1'] = np.nan
```

Pero en cuanto encuentra la primera condición me cambia todos los valores de columna, incluso si no cumplen la condición. También probé con .loc en un bucle pero me daba error.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

En la asignación

```py
df.loc[mask, 'Col2'] = df.loc['Col1']
```

hay un error (de hecho a mi ni me deja ejecutarlo), debido a que `df.loc['Col1']` buscará la cadena 'Col1' en el índice y no en las columnas, y esa entrada no está en el índice. Olvidaste poner qué índices seleccionas, y debes usar otra vez los indicados por `mask`. Es decir:

```py
df.loc[mask, 'Col2'] = df.loc[mask, 'Col1']
```

### Demo completa

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "Col1": ["2m", "11", "15", "4m"],
  "Col2": ["10", "3m", "4m", "25"],
  "Col3": [30, 31, 35, 40]
})
print(df)

mask = df['Col1'].str.contains(r'm', na=True)
df.loc[mask, 'Col2'] = df.loc[mask, 'Col1']
df.loc[mask, 'Col1'] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Muestra `df`  antes y después:

```html
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0   2m   10    30
1   11   3m    31
2   15   4m    35
3   4m   25    40

  Col1 Col2  Col3
0  NaN   2m    30
1   11   3m    31
2   15   4m    35
3  NaN   4m    40
```

Comment: Con la modificación sugerida por @abulafia tampoco me da el resultado deseado. Sigo obteniendo la columna 1 entera de NaN y todos los valores de la columna 1 se han movido a la derecha, sin importar si tienen "m" o no.

Comment: A mí me resulta correcto el código.